# SSIS - ORA-01722 - Invalid Number

Tags: sql, oracle, ssis

I makeing simple SSIS dtsx pack where I select data from Sybase DB and I want to insert them to Oracle DB. Unfortunettly, I am getting ORA-01722 error code, but I cant figure out where I made a mistake.

***First table (Sybase DB):***

```
select * from d_agent
```

Data type for first table:

```
NUMERIC,NUMERIC,DECIMAL,VARCHAR,VARCHAR,VARCHAR,VARCHAR,VARCHAR,VARCHAR,VARCHAR,TIMESTAMP,INTEGER
```

**Data that cant be inserted and error ORA-1722:** `2,5005000,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,22436705,Test,Jun 30 2005, 96`

***Second table (Oracle DB):***

```
ODBC Destination and right table selected copy.d_agent_sez
```

Data type for second table:

```
NUMBER,NUMBER,NUMBER,VARCHAR,VARCHAR,VARCHAR,VARCHAR,VARCHAR,VARCHAR,VARCHAR,DATE,NUMBER
```

SSIS error msg: `[Transfer_ORACLE] Error: Open Database Connectivity (ODBC) error occurred. state: '22018'. Native Error Code: 1722. [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-01722: invalid number`

What am I missing? Please help :)
Thank you for help.

Comment: It would be helpful to include the full SQL statement it's actually executing. Possibly the columns aren't in the order you think?

Comment: @AlexPoole its component from SSIS ODBC destiantion where you select ODBC connector and table where it should go. And thats it.

Comment: You don't have to map the columns? With position and/or data type? If not are you sure the columns are in the same order in the two tables? I don't use SSIS or ODBC so I can't speculate further than that, but good luck *8-)

Comment: Do you have the privilege to convert `DATE` data type to `TIMESTAMP` within the Oracle DB. If so, try to reload again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First problem is to convert timestamp to date >> I think this will not be possible...

Oracle:

For your column with date datatype:

```
create table t1(a date)

insert into t1 values(Jun 30 2005) 
--this will not work
insert into t1 values(to_date('Jun 30 2005', 'Mon DD YYYY'))
--this will work
```

For your column with varchar datatype:

```
create table t2(b varchar(100))
insert into t2 values(Test)
 --this will not work
insert into t2 values('Test')
--this will work
```

When I correct this two things insert is ok...
[Here is a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=412a0d444a3e9cf88f9fe7eb79e0b2e6)

Comment: Hello @VBoka , thank you for your answer. But I couldnt add or modify insert statement in SSIS. There is a component where you choose ODBC connector and table where it should insert the data and thats all. All I can do is to prepare data in select statement or use Data conversion component...

Comment: Hi @JFpoj, can you try and cast values  when selecting ?

Comment: Yes I can try that.

Comment: Hi @JFpoj let me know...

Comment: So, if I have date in TIMESTAMP datatype, I have to convert it to date datatype for ORACLE?

Comment: hi @JFpoj , Well the timestamp column is not a date column, that is the biggest problem I think... Can you change destination table in Oracle and it's columns datatype.... ?

Comment: Thanks for help I will discuss the problem with my collegues and I will write on Monday.

Comment: So, I describe the problem to my colleagues and the fix will be made in Sybase DB where we will change TIMESTAMP to different date datatype. Thank for help :)

Comment: Hi @JFpoj so can we consider my first sentence the correct answer ? :)

Comment: Thank you for accepting a suggestion as correct answer.